# Multiple Automapper Naming Conventions

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have a situation where I want to map using lower underscore to pascal going one way, but pascal to lower underscore the other way. My understanding is that profiles can do this, but I'm struggling with getting it to work. Here's what I have:

```
   Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<FromUnderscoreMapping>();
                cfg.AddProfile<ToUnderscoreMapping>();
            });

   Mapper.CreateMap<ArticleEntity, Article>().WithProfile("FromUnderscoreMapping");

...

        public class FromUnderscoreMapping : Profile
        {
            protected override void Configure()
            {
                SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
                DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
            }

            public override string ProfileName
            {
                get { return "FromUnderscoreMapping"; }
            }
        }

        public class ToUnderscoreMapping : Profile
        {
            protected override void Configure()
            {
                SourceMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
                DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
            }

            public override string ProfileName
            {
                get { return "ToUnderscoreMapping"; }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mapping needs to be moved to the config:

```
public class FromUnderscoreMapping : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
        CreateMap<ArticleEntity, Article>();
    }

    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "FromUnderscoreMapping"; }
    }
}

public class ToUnderscoreMapping : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
        DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
        CreateMap<Article, ArticleEntity>();
    }

    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "ToUnderscoreMapping"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: As an addendum, this answer is correct, but also it turns out that the lower underscore model really needs to be all lower case. Unlike the standard mapping, which is not case sensitive, lower underscore is very much case sensitive.